# Baryon wavefunctions

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, pauli-exclusion-principle, baryons

The textbook I am currently using states that when all quarks have the same flavor, there are no $J=1/2$ baryon wavefunctions for the ground state $l=0$.

Is this an experimental result or is there a theoretical reason for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both. It's fermi statistics.

The overall wavefunction must be totally antisymmetric under any (fermionic) quark interchange. The color part of the wavefunction is antisymmetric, so the *l* and spin wavefucntions must be symmetric. (There is no play in the flavor part of the wavefunction: take the quark to be *s*, so that part is *sss*.)

- So the spin wavefunction is the *symmetric part* of $1/2\otimes 1/2\otimes 1/2$, which is then  necessarily spin 3/2, added to the *l* singlet part, yielding *J*=3/2.

The two spin 1/2 components of the triple spin product are [both of mixed symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29443/adding-3-electron-spins), so cannot be symmetric as required. It is thus impossible to contrive  J=1/2 states!

You appreciate the *actual* $\Omega^-$ is part of the *J*=3/2 decuplet, and there is no such triply strange *J*=1/2 baryon.

Comment: Thank you for the response. As a brief follow up, for the calculation of a proton's magnetic moment the following wavefunction was used: 1/(6)^0.5 (2u↑u↑d↓ - u↑u↓d↑ - u↓u↑d↑). This wavefunction is only antisymmetric under the exchange of the like quarks, yet gave the correct result. Why is this OK to use?

Comment: That's the point: it is in the baryon octet, so it has mixed spin and isospin symmetry, *I* =1/2, (unlike the isosinglet example above.) *J* and *I* "coordinate" to have overall complete symmetry, even though there are antisymmetric "sectors" in each. *u,d* are both involved in the antisymmetric isosinglet, unlike two *u* s.

Comment: [See this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309120/proton-spin-flavor-wavefunction).